# How to enable email sending in CiviRules

Tags: email, civirules

I've installed the Email API for CiviRules, but nothing about emails is showing up under actions in CiviRules. Have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but no change. Is there another step that I need to be taking to enable email sending?

CiviCRM 4.6.33 on Drupal 7.56, CiviRules 1.15, Email API 1.10.

Comment: Might be worth adding an issue to the [civirules github issue](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules) that references this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.emailapi to version 1.11 appears to have fixed this!

Comment: Indeed, fixed in 1.11!

Answer (score 3):

You should try to clear CiviCRM's cache as mentioned in [CiviRules' documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-action/) :

> If you add your action as a a managed entity (which we think is a good idea) you will obviously have to do a {yoursite}/civicrm/clearcache to make sure the new managed entity is available.

Cheers,
Olivier;

Comment: I've tried that, but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue a month ago. After installing both the E-MAIL API and CiviRules I wasn't able to select send email rule, but I could send emails through the API explorer.

In other words everything was working only I wasn't able to select send email action when I defined rules. It turned out that a row was missing from the civirule_action table of the CiviCRM database.

I fixed the issue by adding the missing row (copied over from the CiviCRM instance with working CiviRules) with name emailapi_send
label Send e-mail and class CRM_Emailapi_CivirulesAction.

The table that works should look like this:

[image]

I don't know what caused it, but I suspect the issue arose because CiviRules and E-MAIL API extensions were uninstalled and then installed again couple of times trying to resolve an unrelated issue. I was using the newest CiviCRM version at the time (4.7.27)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so did a combination of the above to fix this on WordPress install:

Added the SQL statement manually:

```
INSERT INTO civirule_action (name, label, class_name, is_active)
VALUES('emailapi_send', 'Send E-mail', 'CRM_Emailapi_CivirulesAction', 1);
```

Deleted the plugin, manually added the v1.11, refreshed cache and it installed properly.  After I was able to execute the v1.7 upgrade and complete the database update.