# Cant install extension E-mail API 1.17

Tags: civirules

wordpress 4.9

And recently upgraded to civicrm 5.22 CiviRules 2.1

Was working fine with older civirules and E-mail API 1.10

this is the error

```
CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "Could not find the SQL file."

#0 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php(190): civicrm_api3("Extension", "install", (Array:1))
#1 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(453): CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions->postProcess()
#2 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#3 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next", "Next")
#4 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next")
#5 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next")
#6 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#7 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(398): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#8 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(156): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit(1, NULL)
#9 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php(121): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
#10 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->run((Array:3), NULL)
#11 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:16))
#12 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#13 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1246): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#14 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#15 /home/domain/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#16 /home/domain/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#17 /home/domain/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#18 /home/domain/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(224): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#19 {main}
```

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Could not find the SQL file.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, there is a typo in there. Fixed in the latest `master` : https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.emailapi.

Comment: Thanks Erik! It installed OK but Send email didn't appear in the actions. I fixed that by adding new row to table civicrm_action as described here https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22099/how-to-enable-email-sending-in-civirules/22105#22105

Comment: Cool, I will add an issue for the send email action for our next sprint or some other community developer that wants to pick it up